Sending OS.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1) to process running in Eclipse
I am trying to use the tactic described in showing-stack-trace-of-running-python-application on a python application running within Eclipse/PyDev. I installed the module described therein (in the file show_stack_trace.py) within the salt.utils directory, which is referenced in PYTHONPATH. I then (following the instructions given in the description) called the listen function of the module and then started the target application in the debugger. I hit a breakpoint and then "Resumed" the execution, which then continued executing. I then tried to send a SIGUSR1 signal, by executing OS.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1) from the Eclipse console. This resulted in an error message,"[Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console". I am insufficiently experienced with using the Eclipse/PyDev debugger to know how to "select the frame". I am not entirely sure that I can send the SIGUSR1 signal using the Eclipse Python console, nor am I sure how to send it any other way. Here is the Eclipse window that shows the situation:

I imagine this is an elementary question, but I am new to using Eclipse/PyDev. Any help would be appreciated. By the way, you may notice that I haven't executed "import os" before calling os.kill. I  noticed this after I did the screen shot, but executing "import os" generated the same error message as os.kill(...).

What is the value of pid variable?

I think you have identified one problem, but not the one causing the "[Invalid Frame] ..." Error. I need to replace pid in os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1) with the actual pid of the process. However, as I mention in the question (edited perhaps after your comment), executing "import os" in the python console causes the same "[Invalid Frame] ..." error as "os.kill(...)"

Look at the list of consoles to the right of the console tab. May be you are at the wrong one.

I think I am in the right console, since it is labeled "1 salt-minion [debug] ..."

Where have you coded the signal handler for SIGUSR1 ?

Purely by trying things at random, I figured out the problem. I needed to be in a different console (as suggested by LMC). I switched to the PyDev console. Then I entered:
import os; import signal; os.kill(14652, signal.SIGUSR1).

14652 is the pid of the process associated with the "frame" of which I wanted to obtain a stack dump. This allowed me to send the SIGUSR1 signal to the process. I now can interrupt the process with the "suicide ..." message (which turns out to be a method name), suspend it and dump the stack history.
